# How to redirect to view from global exception filter in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, global-filter

I am working on a MVC using **asp.net core** where I have created a global filter to handling exceptions.
Its handling exceptions but not redirecting to view(Error.cshtml) which is in **Shared** folder.

Below is my code:

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                return;
            }
            Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "/Error" // also tried with "Error" and "~/Error"
            };
        }
```

Comment: Are you failing making the connection or failing after the connection succeeds (before redirection)?

Comment: its not making the connection

Comment: Then it is failing in the Net Library for the HTTP Request.  Try putting an exception handler (try/catch) around the request.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
  filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

  //Redirect or return a view, but not both.
  filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  // OR 
  filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
  {
     ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"
  };
}
```

Comment: Also mention that he needs to define an action on `Homecontroller` that results with `Error` view, if it doesn't exists.

Comment: its not working for me, I am redirecting on some action using this but its not redirecting there

Comment: try using this ...context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("...");

Comment: now getting this error..     System.InvalidOperationException: 'StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.'

Comment: do like this                                                                            context.ExceptionHandled = true;                                                                            and then context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("...");

Comment: changed above answer have a look at it..i hope this will fix your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205146/discussion-between-ishwar-gagare-and-sunil-bamal).

Answer (score 0):

```
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "controller", "Account" },
                { "action", "Index" },
                { "returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl } 
            });
```

Comment: HttpContext does not contain a definition for RawUrl